# User able to set order of file extensions to hyperlink

Tags: vb.net

I am building a hyperlinking tool. I currently have a `listview1` containing a `column` of all the extensions from files in a particular directory.

For each extension type, there is a corresponding `checkbox` that the user can tick if they would like the extension included or untick if they would like all files with that extension not to be hyperlinked.

I am looking for a different way for the user to interact with the extension list. Is there a way I can list each extension type and have the user manipulate the order they would like the extensions hyperlinked (eg. all .xls files are hyperlinked before .pdf files)?

My current script looks like this:

```
    Private Sub ExtensionFind(ByVal ListView As ListView,
                                    ByVal SearchString As String,
                                    Optional ByVal ColumnIndex As Int32 = Nothing,
                                    Optional ByVal MatchFullText As Boolean = True,
                                    Optional ByVal IgnoreCase As Boolean = True)
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    Dim ListViewColumnIndex As Int32 = ListView.Columns.Count - 1

    If MatchFullText AndAlso IgnoreCase Then
        For Each Item As ListViewItem In ListView.Items
            For X As Int32 = 0 To ListViewColumnIndex
                If Item.SubItems(X).Text.ToLower = ".pdf".ToLower Then
                    CheckBox1.Visible = True

                ElseIf Item.SubItems(X).Text.ToLower = ".msg".ToLower Then
                    CheckBox3.Visible = True
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

The form I am using looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Cg1n.png

Comment: Do you have any examples for that? Images? If there is available example, Please attach it on your question. Thanks.